# Blender glitches in viewport after opening file

Tags: 3d-view

I have been using blender for a pretty long time and I have found this really good model (made in 2.79) ages ago and ran it on my old PC, it worked. When I try to run it on my other PC it just falls apart and looks like blender is having issues displaying it in the viewport. Although this does not affect the final render, it's really annoying to look at this glitch. Note: I am using the exact same file as I used on my older PC and the viewport issue never happened. This error also does not occur in version 2.79.

I am using blender 2.83.5 and these are my PC specs.

16GB Ram

AMD FX(tm)-4100 Quad-Core Processor

NVIDIA GeForce GTX 275 (OLD)

I am running Windows 10.

Here are images showing the glitch.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzmd7.jpg

Comment: Your GPU is below the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.83. Graphics glitches and even crashes can occur on unsupported hardware, mostly because the graphics drivers aren't updated anymore and thus bugs aren't fixed by the GPU vendor.

Comment: Thank you man. I was really confused as to why that happens. I'll make sure to buy a new graphics card as soon as I get the money to. Have a nice day!

Comment: You're welcome. There may be some workarounds possible if you're building Blender yourself, but it would generally be a good idea to use a more recent GPU. See ticket [T71576](https://developer.blender.org/T71576) for more information about the potential workaround.

Comment: What GPU would you recommend for home use of blender?

Comment: That entirely depends on your budget and if you want to use GPU rendering as well. You probably shouldn't buy anything earlier than the GeForce 10 series.

Comment: Yeah that's true, I've seen how GPU rendering is 2 times faster than CPU rendering but I can't spend that much. Can a GTX 1650 do GPU rendering well?

Comment: Yes it can be used for GPU rendering. For rendering speed comparisons between different GPUs take a look at https://opendata.blender.org/